# How to pass config/constants file from one module to another in Java Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, cloud, config

I want to pass config or constants java file from one module to another. How to do that?

**Details:** It is a multi-module spring-boot project. I want to pass different config at application startup using String args[] that is usually passed in the Main class.

Answer (score 0):

can you please add more details to your question? if these 2 modules are spring-boot apps then you can have common configs/constants in the db table and read from there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
Yes, it is a spring-boot multi-module maven project. 
I was hoping if I can make use of String args[] (of the main method of Java) in some way to pass the different configurations.